# Reactjs: css causes reactjs result to jam together

Tags: css, reactjs

The code below displays result from reactjs arrays and everything is okay.

**What Am now trying to achieve:**

I am now trying to display reactjs results at the right hand side using **css**. 
To this effect, I have created a Css class called **Side-Bar** within **user.css** files.

**Here is my issue:**

when I run the reactjs code with the css, the Css causes the reactjs result to be jammed with each other but
 If I remove the css, everything will be displayed (but with no css to position at the right)

below is where and how am calling the css class `className="sidebar"`

```
<div className="sidebar">
    <ul>

        <div  key={this.props.data.id}>
          <button >{this.props.data.name}</button>
        </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

**user.css**

```
.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
  text-align: bottom;
}
```

**Reactjs code**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import './user.css';



class Person extends React.Component {
  state = { open: false };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
  <div className="sidebar">
    <ul>

        <div  key={this.props.data.id}>
          <button >{this.props.data.name}</button>
        </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      showBox: false,
      data: [
        { id: "1", name: "user 1" },
        { id: "2", name: "user 2" },
        { id: "3", name: "user 3" },
        { id: "4", name: "user 4" },
        { id: "5", name: "user 5" }
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map(person => (
          <Person key={person.id} data={person} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the expected result? Why do you need `position: fixed`?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using flex as per code below which i implement inside user.css files and then call it as class

```
.sidebar{
    display: flex; justify-content: flex-end
}
```